# Regression: Interactions terms of factors with several levels (interpretation)

Tags: regression, categorical-data, interaction, linear-model

I'm running the following linear model in R:

```
lm(formula = Valence ~ StatusOfMandarin * Condition, data = d_afraid, 
    na.action = na.omit)
```

My data is as follow :

- N = 1400
- Outcome variable = 'Valence', i.e. rating from 0 to 800 (participants saw or heard a Mandarin speaker and had to rate how pleasant the speaker was feeling)
- Predictors =
  1) 'Status of Mandarin', i.e. 3-level factor (whether the participants are native speakers (`L1`) / learners (`LX`) / non-speakers of Mandarin (`L0`) ) --> baseline level = `L1`
  2) 'Condition', i.e. 4-level factor (whether the participants saw a video recording without sound (`Visual`)/ heard an audio recording (`VocalVerbal`) / saw & heard a video recording with sound (`VisualVocalVerbal`) / only heard a blurred audio recording (`Vocal`)) --> baseline level = `VisualVocalVerbal`

The result is:

```
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-345.70 -112.20  -23.47   82.12  544.89 

Coefficients:
                                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                              262.944     11.564  22.737  < 2e-16 ***
StatusOfMandarinLX                       -29.754     19.282  -1.543 0.123044    
StatusOfMandarinL0                       -71.835     19.811  -3.626 0.000299 ***
ConditionVisual                            2.534     16.893   0.150 0.880788    
ConditionVocal                           101.760     16.754   6.074 1.63e-09 ***
ConditionVocalVerbal                       5.202     25.093   0.207 0.835802    
StatusOfMandarinLX:ConditionVisual        11.433     28.464   0.402 0.688005    
StatusOfMandarinL0:ConditionVisual        -2.208     27.406  -0.081 0.935806    
StatusOfMandarinLX:ConditionVocal         13.748     27.689   0.497 0.619617    
StatusOfMandarinL0:ConditionVocal         81.745     27.354   2.988 0.002856 ** 
StatusOfMandarinLX:ConditionVocalVerbal  -19.931     34.365  -0.580 0.562017    
StatusOfMandarinL0:ConditionVocalVerbal   67.933     33.097   2.053 0.040315 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 154.3 on 1324 degrees of freedom
  (143 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.1356,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1284 
F-statistic: 18.88 on 11 and 1324 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I plotted the data to try and make the interpretation easier.
[image: Plot]

My problem is that I am not sure what is the baseline to which the significant interaction term `StatusMandarinL0:ConditionVocal` is compared to. Is the mean rating in this group 81.745 unites higher than the mean in `StatusofMandarinL1:ConditionVisualVocalVerbal` (combination of the baselines of the main factors) ?

Comment: Use getME(fm2, "X") you can get the design matrix X, from X, you can find which one is set as reference. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/325516/random-effects-design-matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StatusMandarin has 3 levels. LX and LO which appear as effects in the models as contrasts (mean differences) with respect to the referent level, which according to the boxplot is taken to be L1. The referent level for Condition is VisualVocalVerbal.

The statistically significant effect of `StatusOfMandarinL0:ConditionVocal` which is the teal box in the 3rd (right) group of boxplot clusters, means that the mean for that group is statistically significantly different from the salmon-colored box in the 1st (left) group.

Comment: That confirms what I thought, thank you @AdamO. If you allow me one follow-up question:
Suppose that I would expect a significant difference between the `VisualVocalVerbal` (salmon box) and the `Visual` (green box) condition among L1, but not among LX and L0. This model does not allow me to answer whether this hypothesis is true, since the "baseline" of all the interaction terms is  `StatusOfMandarinL1:ConditionVisualVocalVerbal`, right?

Comment: @Pernelle a couple approaches. Fit the stratified models using the `subset=StatusOfMandarin == "L1"` command (2 more times for `L0` and `LX`). and inspect the effects. Or use a post-hoc analysis with `tukeyHSD(fit.obj)` where `fit.obj` is your stored lm fit object. Sleuth through there for the comparisons you're interested in.

Comment: I have tried both your suggestions. I was wondering whether I can safely interpret the p-values of the TukeyHSD although my data does not meet the assumptions of normality and homoskedasticity. (N.B: I apply the TuckeyHSD to a bootstrapped lm, but I guess it is still problematic, isn't it?)

Comment: @Pernelle that's a separate question: in fact, two, at least. You'll find a billion responses on SE if you make good use of search.

Answer (score 1):

If you group all terms in your model which include StatusOfMandarinL0, you get this:

```
(-71.835 - 2.208 x ConditionVisual + 81.745 x ConditionVocal + 67.933 x ConditionVocalVerbal) x StatusOfMandarinL0
```

This allows you to tease out the (estimated) effect of StatusOfMandarinL0 for each condition. In particular:

Effect of StatusOfMandarinL0 for the baseline condition, VisualVocalVerbal, is estimated to be -71.835;

Effect of StatusOfMandarinL0 for ConditionVisual is -71.835 + (-2.208);

Effect of StatusOfMandarinL0 for ConditionVocal is -71.835 + (81.745);

Effect of StatusOfMandarinL0 for ConditionVocalVerbal is -71.835 + (67.933).

So you can see that each interaction term helps determine how the effect of StatusOfMandarinL0 on Valence for the respective non-baseline condition differs (on an additive scale) from the effect of StatusOfMandarinL0 on Valence for the baseline condition.